# Copy/use parent method using local variables [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

Let's say I have two classes (parent and child) defined like so.

Parent method in parent.py:

```
c = 1

def Parent(object):
   def foo():
      print(c)
```

Child method in child.py:

```
c = 2

def Child(Parent):
   def foo():
      super().foo()
```

Creating a Child instance and using *foo* method would print 1, but is there a way to make the *foo* method print 2 instead.

In other words, I want all Parent methods to use local variable (defined in child.py file) if they are defined outside the method scope.

Comment: What you are asking for is called dynamic scope, but Python doesn't support that. Instead, you should just make this a class variable

Answer (score 0):

### If c is defined inside child one

Use this if you are using child one as a class created inside parent class. Make sure you have initialised child class by

```
parent.child=parent.child()
```

Then put this in child class

```
def foo(self):
     print(self.c)
```